# What is the hash method for minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I heard that if you input a non-number into the seed box (or a number larger than 2⁶⁴), it will use a hash method to turn this into a number (less than or equal to 2⁶⁴). My question:
What is the hash method Minecraft uses? (I use the Bedrock Edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)#General), the hash function used is the Java `String.hashCode()`, which is computed as:

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

(where s[i] is the i-th character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation)

Which is clearly a Java method. However, considering that seeds are somewhat compatible across editions, this algorithm could be true for both Java and Bedrock.

Comment: But what is the numerical value of a certain character? is it the Unicode number?

Comment: Yes it's the Unicode number, at least on [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))